# add / remove classes to body on scroll - tweaking some existing scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just looking for some help please with some javascript tweaking of the script in the html code below.

The script adds / removes a sticky class to the body element when scrolling up and/or down a page.

My 2 questions are...

a. Is it possible to delay adding the .sticky class for 1 second?
If so, what new code would achieve this?

b. Is it possible to automatically remove the .sticky class (eg to autohide the .test div) if there is no interaction with the .test item after 2 seconds - and then reapply the classes on re scrolling (and so on)?
If so, what new code would achieve this?

**This is my working example - hopefully the javascript can be tweaked for delay and auto hide per a. and b. above**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" class="dont-sticky2">
<head>

<style>
body { background: white; }
body.sticky { background: grey; }
.test { width: 150px; height :150px; top: auto; position: relative; background: #ccc; }
body.sticky .test { top: 0; position: sticky; background: yellow; }
</style>

</head>
<body style="height:5000px;">

<h1>Scroll Test 1 (working)</h1>

<div class="test">Testing.</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// source: https://diviengine.com/snippet-how-to-add-a-css-class-to-divi-on-scroll/
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    function stickyCheck(){ 
        if ( $(window).width() >= 991  && $(window).scrollTop() >= 250 && !$('html').hasClass('dont-sticky') ) {
            $('body').addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    }
    stickyCheck(); 
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
        stickyCheck();
    });
  
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Confirming that I am not a javascripter so please go easy on me :)

edited per feedback: original post streamlined from 3 scripts to 1.

**edited per CBroe's comment re setTimeout and clearTimeout.**

The way I have tried to implement setTimeout and clearTimeout:

- setTimeout seems to occur on page load rather than scroll.
- clearTimeout messes with the sticky class being removed when expected.

I tried in the window.scroll.function too but that didn't seem right either.
Any ideas?

I am javascript challenged :)

Any code help greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    function stickyCheck(){ 
        if ( $(window).width() >= 991  && $(window).scrollTop() >= 250 && !$('html').hasClass('dont-sticky') ) {
            setTimeout(() => { 
                $('body').addClass('sticky');
                alert('setTimout set') 
            }, 2000);
        } else {
            clearTimeout(() => { 
                $('body').removeClass('sticky');
                alert('setTimout cleared') 
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
    stickyCheck(); 
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
            stickyCheck();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm finding it really hard to not only read this question but also identify what the actual problem is. Looks to me like you have at least 12 questions in your question.

Comment: please produce a minimal reproducible example. nobody is going to read 8 pages of your question just to understand what the problem is.

Comment: roger that. apologies, I went a bit overboard trying to get 3 scripts tweaked to help evaluation. Post edited to just the one script with 2 questions a - delay / timer and b - autohide if not used. Hopefully that is clearer now :)

Comment: For "timers" in JS in general, go read up on `setTimeout`. _"if there is no interaction with the .test item after 2 seconds"_ - depends on your exact definition of "interaction with", but will involve `setTimeout`as well - and its counterpart `clearTimeout`, to cancel a timeout you started when the sticky class was applied, when that "interaction" with the element happens (onmouseover, onclick, whatever.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe. Hmmm, I am not very good at javascript, this is tricky for my css brain. I can get the scroll delay sort of working with setTimeout, (though not sure if that is where I should put the code) but I must be using clearTimeout incorrectly as that doesn;t seem to do anything and the sticky class remains on the body element when scrolling to the top of the page. I pasted the edited code into the bottom of the original thread if you have time to have a look. What I would like to achieve - delay adding sticky class when scrolling; clear any timer when sticky class removed.